# c++ cli wrapper design issue

Tags: design-patterns, struct, c++-cli

I am in the process of writing a c++ cli wrapper for a unmanaged mfc dll. My current design looks like this.

Lets say i have a unmanaged struct i want to wrap that looks like follows:

```
struct
{
    int firstValue;
    int secondValue;
}somestruct;
```

My approach for doing this is right now by first creating a header which declares setters and getters for my struct:

```
class somestructWrapper
{
    void* SomeStruct;

    int GetFirstValue();
    void SetFirstValue(int n);
    int GetSecondValue();
    void SetSecondValue(int n);
};
```

This header does not know about the struct it just keeps a void* for it which is allocated in the cpp.

I will then make a cpp file where i include the struct somestruct and implement the getters/setters.

After doing this i then make a c++ file with /clr enabled that holds a somestructWrapper and give me access to the functions from managed code.

```
public ref class SomeStruct
{
    SomeStructWrapper* someStructWrapper
    property int FirstValue
    {
        int get()
        {
            return someStructWrapper->GetFirstValue();
        }
        set(int n)
        {
            someStructWrapper->SetFirstValue(n);
        }
    }
    ..............
}
```

I first tried to do this directly in the class with /clr enabled but it wouldnt compile as soon as i included a file from my dll(this is the reason that i have the somestructWrapper class to provide me with a clean header).

I have structs with 50-100 attributes and its kind of time consuming to first write setter/getter and then make a property in the managed class for each attribute.

Is there a more clean approach for accomplishing this?

Comment: You should't have to wrap struct in native class just to wrap it again in CLR. What were the compilation errors when you tried to include the dll headers directly? Try including it only in the implementation file of the CLI wrapper, not in its header file (forward declare it there)

Comment: You likely do not need that wrapper.

Comment: I would suggest cleaning up the header file if you can (windows.h sounds like a hassle but with it, it's often the *order* of includes that matters). Other alternative is to replicate the compilation options of the native C++ wrapper file in CLR file. Check your precompiled headers as well. I usually have a separate precompiled headers for the native compilation units and CLI compilation units.

Comment: The precompiled header for the file holding the struct. Just create a fresh CLR class, delete *everything* from its header and implementation file and then include your native dll header. That way you'll isolate the native header issues in CLR compilation unit.

Comment: You have to enable it for the .cpp file that includes it as headers aren't compiled. So you have to enable it in compilation options. Or take what you have right now in the file that implements `public ref class SomeStruct`, delete everything from it and then include the header. VS will likely complain of missing precompiled header. Turn it off for the duration of the testing (also in compiler options for the specific file) as you don't want CLI precompiled header while you are trying to clean up your dll header. Maybe it will compile without it in which case - you know where the problem is.

Comment: `afxole.h`... ouch... The errors "not support default-int" means that the definition of the type was never seen before by the compiler (e.g. 'my_never_defined_type function()` will *sometimes* give you that error)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48385/discussion-between-ierceg-and-k4rlsson)

Answer (score 1):

We traced the problem, or at least the first layer of it, to a recompiled header being included in `somestruct` header. This was pulling in all sorts of Windows headers and messing with the CLR compilation. Such large and pervasive headers should only be included in .cpp files leaving other compilation units to define their own (or if they are using the same precompiled header, it should, again, be included from the .cpp file)